# SAPUI5 oModel.create() with Array

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I have a OData Model in my application, where I want to add a new entry.
This code works fine in my case:

```
            ODataModel.createEntry("/showcaseSet", {
                properties: { 
                    "property": "Haris"
                }
             });
```

But when I am doing the same with array it doesnt work:

```
            var oEntry = [];
            oEntry.push(
                {
                    "property": "Haris"
                }
            );

            ODataModel.createEntry("/showcaseSet", oEntry);
```

When I am submitting the chages from the Model to my backend, I don't recieving any data from the frontend. Only when I am working in the first case or code i described.

Do you know where my problem is?

Answer (score 1):

In `v2.ODataModel`, the [`createEntry` API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/createEntry) is expecting just an object in the second argument, **not an array**.

In that case, you could do something like this:

```js
oEntry.forEach(e => ODataModel.createEntry("/showcaseSet", e));
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But in the API reference it says that you can use too an Array. My problem is that I have to create a dynamic Object, which can have dynamic properties and this I could solve with a Array. Because I dont know how to create a dynamic Object, I think this is not possible

Comment: The call of my ABAP code is working, but I dont recieve any data in my ls_data variable when working with oEntry.push, altough I am using the same syntax for the property definition

Comment: @hariskkkk _> But in the API reference it says that you can use too an Array_ ... You were probably reading the [`createEntry` from the `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel#methods/createEntry) of which the entire model is **deprecated**. Please clarify in the question which `ODataModel` exactly you are using as the list of arguments can vary.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// binding against this entity
oForm.setBindingContext(oContext);
// submit the changes (creates entity at the backend)
oModel.submitChanges({success: mySuccessHandler, error: myErrorHandler});
```